# ZendX Jquery Form Autocomplete

Tags: zend-framework, zendx

Hi i'm using zendx_jquery_form_autocomplete.
I have a mysql database with a table user. User has a ID and a Name.
My problem is that i don't know I can do my research in the Name column and have the id of the right row.
In the tutorial that i saw there is a research in a array and that work fine but now i shoul pass the id of my research...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql like operator for your search in rows.

```
$param =  $this->_getParam('param'); //send from autocomplete

$result = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->select()->from('users','user_id')->where('name like =?',"%$param")->query()->fetchAll();
```